# Cutting volume down

Tags: bodybuilding, resistancetraining, progress

I'm currently on a cut while maintaining my resistance training, that is 3x/week FBW with a total of 12 sets per body part. I have recently started to notice that my regeneration is kinda compromised and also would prefer to spend less time in the gym. I thought about reducing my weekly volume to 9 sets per body part, while obviously still maintaining progressive overload. However, I am afraid that the sudden drop in weekly volume will make my muscle switch to "we dont have to do as much as before so we choose not to grow" mode. Seems dumb, but is there anything to worry about? Can I still make gains (provided that I finish my cut) with lower volume?

Comment: One solution is to switch to compound movements to cut down time in the gym. Adding this as a comment since it does not directly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

To a certain extent, volume isn't really important. What's important is RPE during sets and overall intensity of training. I have seen the most significant amount of gains since implementing a high intensity, low volume routine. For instance, for chest I do 3 exercises (1 lower press, 1 upper press, and 1 fly movement), snd all for only 2 working sets. I train chest every 5 days doing 6 sets per workout, which averages out at roughly 8 sets per week. As stated, the overall intensity and exertion is the most important factor and doing a lower volume of set allows you to throw much more intensity into each set and go to failure every time.

To conclude, low volume can be very effective and, in my opinion, more effective than higher volume.

Edit: [This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4562558/) study shows that although the higher intensity workouts showed a greater increase in strength than volume after the trial, it also showed a slight but not insignificant edge in muscle mass/hypertrophy too.

Comment: Personal experience is one thing, but can you back this up with published research? My read of the literature is that, individual variation notwithstanding, volume is a key driver of hypertrophy.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov - reference added.

Answer (score 0):

How to reduce the amount of time you spend in your workout sessions? Split your volume more throughout the week, like a 4 day, 5 day, or 6 day split. Or reduce weekly volume of current split. That's all there is to that part.

**More importantly;**

If you noticed that something is up with your recovery rate, it means:

1. You might really be in an unnecessarily large caloric deficit.
2. Not enough rest given to muscles.
3. (anything else I missed)

So if it's (1), make sure you are on track with your diet, a slow steady cut is better than a rushed cut, that way you can preserve more muscle too. And, it's better to evenly spread your meals IF possible.

If it's (2), each muscle group should have at least  48 hours of rest in between. But IDEALLY at least like 2 full non working-out days to that respective muscle. For example, *Upper -> Lower -> REST -> Upper -> Lower -> REST -> REST*.

So since your 3xFBW/week routine can't do this, I suggest shifting into *Lower -> Upper -> REST -> REST-> Full Body -> REST -> REST*. Hitting a muscle twice a week is totally fine given you well stimulated it into hypertrophy. Focus mainly on *muscle tension* rather than *metabolic stress*, meaning take enough rest until you're totally ready for your next set (generally that's around 3 minutes). Start out maintaining the **same volume** per week, if your body doesn't respond well to it, **reduce slowly** experimentally weekly.

Of course the issue can be a combination of both (1) and (2). And who knows, it could be (3) too. But try out my suggestions and see.

Oh and if you're starting the *Lower -> Upper -> REST -> REST-> Full Body -> REST -> REST* split, take about 2 full rest days and then start it, alright!